# How to Correctly Layout Android Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

So I'm new to android and am needing some advice and help with a layout I'm wanting to implement.

So I'm wanting to put two or more controls next to each other in a single row... I'm using a LinearLayout to achieve this. But what I've had to do is the control on the left I have given a width to push the other control to the right side... SO I picked up on a problem with this on different screen resolutions. If the resolution is not as high as my testing device (Samsung S3) then the control on the right gets squashed as it can't move due to the width of the control on the left.

What I'm needing is something like Bootstrap pull-left and pull-right and then I can just set the padding from left or right which would solve my problem... How would I achieve this in Android?

High Resolution
[image: High Resolution]

Lower Resolution
[image: Lower Resolution]

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity$TestFragment" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="7dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Test Label"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/light_grey"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try using android:layout_weight="0.5" in both textview and edittext

Comment: check and tell me the result

Comment: This seems to work but because some of my labels are longer than others the EditText Views are all different sizes which I don't like. Is there away to control the width of the EditText as it seems you can't when using layout_weight

Answer (score 0):

you can create put your layouts to smaller devices to layout-small, layout-large

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

```
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
```

It's bad using this to layouts, you should use wrap_content or layout_weight